# How to make the wget python module not download duplicates?

Tags: python, wget

When trying to download a file from a post on 4chan (through BASC_py4chan) and downloading it through wget, wget will download the file even if I make a if statement saying not to download it if the filename is the same as a filename in the current directory? Is this a wget-python problem or did I make a mistake?

```
    if 'ylyl' in subject or 'YLYL' in subject:
    for post in thread.all_posts:
        if post.has_file:
            print(post.filename)
            for filename in os.listdir(cwd):
                print(filename)
                if filename != post.filename:
                    url = post.file_url
                    wget.download(url)
                    time.sleep(1.03)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an issue with your code. The problem is at this point:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(cwd):
        print(filename)
        if filename != post.filename:
            url = post.file_url
            wget.download(url)
            time.sleep(1.03)
```

You are looping through each file in the directory. That means if you have a single file in the directory that is not named the same as the post's filename, it's going to download.

So let's say your code is trying to download file3 and your directory contains file1, file2, and file3.

With those files in the directory your if statement is going to make these 3 checks.

```
        if 'file1' != 'file3':
            url = post.file_url
            wget.download(url)
            time.sleep(1.03)

        if 'file2' != 'file3':
            url = post.file_url
            wget.download(url)
            time.sleep(1.03)

        if 'file3' != 'file3':
            url = post.file_url
            wget.download(url)
            time.sleep(1.03)
```

What you might want to try instead is checking if the filename is in the list that os.listdir() returns.

Here is my solution:

```
if 'ylyl' in subject or 'YLYL' in subject:
for post in thread.all_posts:
    if post.has_file:
        print(post.filename)
        if post.filename not in os.listdir(cwd):
            url = post.file_url
            wget.download(url)
            time.sleep(1.03)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your code to

```
if 'ylyl' in subject or 'YLYL' in subject:
    for post in thread.all_posts:
        if post.has_file:
        print(post.filename)
        # changed at here
        if post.filename not in os.listdir(cwd):
            url = post.file_url
            wget.download(url)
            time.sleep(1.03)
```